# animate ::before content on :hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

The following css is to have the `$` sign appear on either side of the `Click` text within `<label></label>`. However, I'd also like to make the `$` content move left and right respectively on hover using only css. I'm not entirely sure how I can accomplish that since the `$` is a pseudo element

```css
#foo:hover ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #e0e0e0 0%, #B7B7B7 50%, #B7B7B7 100%);
}

label::before, label::after {
   content: "$";
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="foo">Click</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the pseudos to position absolute, and z-index -1 to be behind the label.

on hover, move them

```css
#foo:hover ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #e0e0e0 0%, #B7B7B7 50%, #B7B7B7 100%);
}


label {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
}
label::before, label::after {
   content: "$";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}

label::before {
   right: calc(100% - 10px);
   transition: right 1s;
}
label:hover::before {
    right: 100%;
}
label::after {
   left: calc(100% - 10px);
   transition: left 1s;
}
label:hover::after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="foo">Click</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the transition property

```css
#foo:hover ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #e0e0e0 0%, #B7B7B7 50%, #B7B7B7 100%);
  position: relative;
}

label::before, label::after {
  content: "$";
  position: relative; 
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

#foo:hover ~ label::before,
label:hover::before{
  left: -10px;
}

#foo:hover ~ label::after,
label:hover::after{
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="foo">Click</label>
</div>
```